# ASP.NET Module Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, module, dependencies

During the design of a new generic authentication framework for some of our products, I have come across an architectural issue I cannot seem to find a good solution for.

I have tried to simplify the problem in order to easily explain it.

The library has two classes:

**Manager** Is responsible for storing currently authenticated users.

**Module** It is the responsibility for the module to validate each request according to security policies. The Module must ask the manager to determine whether a user is currently authenticated.

Now the manager is supplied an implementation of an interface which allows the manager to load users from a repository. The specific implementation is not contained in this library. Because of this, I cannot directly instantiate an instance of the repository within the library.

I have no way of modifying properties or supplying arguments for the module constructor. So my question is this, how can I give the module a reference to an instance of the Manager?

```
namespace Demo
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        object GetUser(int id);
    }
```

`public class Manager
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; private set; }

    public Manager(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }
}

public class Module : IHttpModule
{
    // How can i access an instance of the manager class here
    // when I am unable to instantiate an instance of
    // of an implementation of the IRepository interface.
}`

}

Comment: This is a little vague, can you post some pseudocode implementation to demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic ASP.NET, I prefer to implement an interface on my `HttpApplication` (`Global`) that declares the necessary dependencies. Here, it's `IHasManager` (the app was written by lolcats):

```
public class Module: IHttpModule {
    Manager manager;
    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        IHasManager application = context as IHasManager;
        if (application != null) {
            manager = application.Manager;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest (if ugly) ways is to stuff your Manager instance into application dictionary after you create it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["Demo.Manager"] = new Manager(new Repository());
```

Now you can access it in your module with:

```
var manager = HttpContext.Current.Application["Demo.Manager"] as Manager;
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this.

think it should do what you need

http://ninject.org/